# Have an error using fmincon in MATLAB (error in barrier line 402)

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to optimize the objective function

```
function f = Objfun(u,x0)
[T,X] = ode45(@(t,x)eqs(t,x,u), [0 132], x0);
f = -X(end,2)*X(end,4);
end
```

The optimization is using fmincon and is shown below

```
clc; close all; clear ;
X1 = [1.5 0 0 7];
lb = 0;
ub = 50;
[x, fval] = fmincon(@(u)Objfun(u, X1), 11.25, [],[],[],[], lb,ub,@(u)nonlincon(u,X1));
```

The function for the nonlinear constraint is:

```
function [c,ceq] = nonlincon(u,x0)
[T,x] = ode45(@(t,x)eqs(t,x,u), [0 132], x0);
c = [];
c(:,1) = -x(:,1);
c(:,2) = x(:,1) - 10;
c(:,3) = -x(:,3);
c(:,4) = x(:,3) - 25;
c(:,5) = -x(:,4);
c(:,6) = x(:,4) - 10;
ceq = [];
end
```

The error I'm getting is as below:

```
 In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
 Error in barrier (line 402)
Error in fmincon (line 818)
    [X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN] = barrier(funfcn,X,A,B,Aeq,Beq,l,u,confcn,options.HessFcn, ...
Error in SolveUwoBound (line 6)
[x, fval] = fmincon(@(u)Objfun(u, X1), 11.25, [],[],[],[], lb,ub,@(u)nonlincon(u,X1));
```

What is the problem here?